# Sum broken into two sub-sums according to a condition on the terms

Tags: programming, summation

I have a sum in mind, but I want to break it into two sums and get a separate total for each of the two.

1. All cases where the square root is accurate, i.e., exact
2. All cases where the square root is not accurate, i.e., inexact.

```
Sum[1/Sqrt[k], {k, 1 , 2003}]
```

Comment: Accurate?  Not accurate?  What do these mean here?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Probably means "Integer", "not integer". Language issues

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/442).

Comment: **1/Sqrt[1]+1/Sqrt[4]+1/Sqrt[9]+1/Sqrt[16]+....+** ...>accurate

Answer (score 5):

Following belisarius's interpretation of your question, and if the total number of terms is not too large, I might write:

```
Total /@ (1.0/GroupBy[Array[Sqrt, 2003], IntegerQ])
```

> ```
> <|True -> 4.37273, False -> 83.6879|>
> ```

Another formulation:

```
fn[x_Integer] := {1.0/x, 0};
fn[x_] := {0, 1.0/x}

Sum[fn @ Sqrt[k], {k, 1, 2003}]
```

> ```
> {4.37273, 83.6879}
> ```

Neither of these will be particularly efficient but you did not state that as a goal and your question remains somewhat ambiguous.

---

### Explanation

#### `GroupBy` method

This method starts by building an [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html) of all square roots of integers one through 2003.  Then the `GroupBy` operator is applied with the parameter `IntegerQ`.  This collects all integer values into one pile and all non-integer values into another.  The output is an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) expression.

```
GroupBy[{1, 2, Pi, E}, IntegerQ]
```

> ```
> <|True -> {1, 2}, False -> {π, E}|>
> ```

`Association` is specially handled by many operations, so for example multiplication is passed down to the values, and since they are lists and multiplication is [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) they are applied to each individual value:

```
x / <|True -> {1, 2}, False -> {π, E}|>
```

> ```
> <|True -> {x, x/2}, False -> {x/π, x/E}|>
> ```

[`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) the [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) function over this expression and you get the sums for each list:

```
 Total /@ <|True -> {x, x/2}, False -> {x/π, x/E}|>
```

> ```
> <|True -> (3 x)/2, False -> x/E + x/π|>
> ```

If you wish the values can be extracted with [`Values`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html):

```
% // Values
```

> ```
> {(3 x)/2, x/E + x/π}
> ```

#### `Sum`

This method uses a symbolic `Sum` leveraging the fact that lists of the same length can be added:

```
{a1, b1} + {a2, b2} + {a3, b3}
```

> ```
> {a1 + a2 + a3, b1 + b2 + b3}
> ```

So the function `fn` transforms its output into either the form `{num, 0}` for integer cases, or `{0, num}` for non-integer cases.  The inversion is applied as part of this function also, because I wanted raw `Sqrt` intput to the function for the purpose of pattern matching.

Comment: This isn't different enough from your solution to post as a separate answer, but I want to record it because it incorporates language closer to what I think is the OP's concept of the problem. `Total /@ KeyMap[If[#, "exact-root-sum", "inexact-root-sum"] &, 1.0/GroupBy[Array[Sqrt, 2003], ExactNumberQ]]` which produces `<|"exact-root-sum" -> 4.37273, "inexact-root-sum" -> 83.6879|>`

Comment: Total /@ (1.0/GroupBy[Array[Sqrt, 2003], IntegerQ])

    <|True -> 4.37273, False -> 83.6879|>

Another formulation:

fn[x_Integer] := {1.0/x, 0};
fn[x_] := {0, 1.0/x}

Sum[fn @ Sqrt[k], {k, 1, 2003}]

    {4.37273, 83.6879}

**it could explain one bit code** ?

Comment: @juan I added some explanation for my code.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sum[If[IntegerQ[#], {1, 0}, {0, 1}]*1/# &@Sqrt[k], {k, 1, 2003}] // N
```

or

```
Sum[If[# ∈ Rationals, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]*# &[1/Sqrt[k]], {k, 1,  2003}] // N
```

both return

> `{4.37273, 83.6879}`

Comment: You can replace `Total@Table` with `Sum`.

Comment: Why not start with `Sum` in your answer?

Comment: Is not that, like, thanks

Comment: @juanmuñoz Hope my revised answer does what you want.