# Using the solve function for big numbers, getting a failure now

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, polynomials, number-theory, big-numbers

When I try to solve:

```
Solve[y^2==441+48*x*(1+x)(-13+16*x)&&1100*10^9<=y<=1200*10^9&&x>=2,{y,x},Integers]
```

My code runs for 169 seconds and spits out `{}` which means that it didn't find any solutions. Now when I change my code to:

```
Solve[y^2==441+48*x*(1+x)(-13+16*x)&&1200*10^9<=y<=1400*10^9&&x>=2,{y,x},Integers]
```

I get the following failure (`Solve::svars` error):

[image]

> Question: is there a way to solve for larger values of $y$ without getting that failure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, I just posted [an answer yesterday](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212480/4999) that overcame just this problem with the undocumented option `"SolveDiscreteSolutionBound"` that controls a system limit:

```
With[{ropts = SystemOptions["ReduceOptions"]},
  Internal`WithLocalSettings[
   SetSystemOptions[
    "ReduceOptions" -> "SolveDiscreteSolutionBound" -> (1400*10^9)],
   Solve[y^2 == 441 + 48*x*(1 + x) (-13 + 16*x) && 
     1200*10^9 <= y <= 1400*10^9 && x >= 2, {y, x}, Integers],
   SetSystemOptions[ropts]
   ]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {406.301, {}}  -- i.e., no solutions found *)
```

I thought I might need to set the bound to `(1400*10^9)^2` because of the `y^2` in the equation, but I guess by "SolutionBound", they really mean the bound on the solution, namely, `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a direct search using a fast square test from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207813):

```
sQ[n_] := FractionalPart@Sqrt[n + 0``1] == 0

Reap[Do[If[sQ[441 + 48*x*(1 + x) (-13 + 16*x)], Sow[x]], {x, 2*10^7}]][[2,1]] //AbsoluteTiming

(*    {91.0767, {1}}    *)
```

So in 91 seconds we've checked up to $x\le2\times10^7$, which corresponds to $y\le2478\times10^9$.

Using parallel processing, I searched up to $x\le10^9$ and found no more solutions:

```
search[x1_Integer, x2_Integer] := Module[{},
  Print[{x1, x2}];
  Flatten[Reap[Do[If[sQ[441 + 48*x*(1 + x) (-13 + 16*x)], Sow[x]], {x,x1,x2}]][[2]]]]

Union @@ Parallelize[
  search @@@ BlockMap[# - {0, 1} &, Range[0, 1000] 10^6 + 1, 2, 1], 
  Method -> "FinestGrained"]

(*    {1}    *)
```

Comment: And if I want to check $x$ between $10^5$ and $10^9$ how do I do that?

Comment: I used that in the Q&A I linked to in my answer, too, and in a comment to @Okkes's answer.  This is the 3rd elliptic curve Q in the last two days, that I've noticed.

Comment: @Jan please see the documentation for [Do](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html). You can do `{x, 10^5, 10^9}` for example. This will take a while though.

Comment: In your edited, you say that you checked $x$ until $10^9$ but I do not see that number back in your code. Where did you put that bound? Can here also be used a lower and an upper bound of $x$, so like $10^5\le x\le10^9$

Comment: @Jan look at the part `Range[0, 1000]*10^6`. I can only show you how; I cannot understand it for you.

Comment: @Roman Oh yes I see. What is the reason that you put the 1000 inside the range function?

Comment: @Jan Try breaking it down like this: Execute `Range[0, 1000] 10^6 + 1` and then `BlockMap[# - {0, 1} &, Range[0, 1000] 10^6 + 1, 2, 1]` -- maybe look up `BlockMap` if you don't understand what it's doing.  And then maybe execute `"f" @@@ BlockMap[# - {0, 1} &, Range[0, 1000] 10^6 + 1, 2, 1]` and imagine what happens when `"f"` is replaced by `search`. Note `@@@` is a form of `Apply`, which you can also look up if it's unfamiliar.