# Using Parallelize in a solve function

Tags: equation-solving, parallelization, number-theory, timing, big-numbers

Is there a way to use Parallelize the following operation, in order to make it do the calculations faster? Or is there another way to speed up this calculation?

```
With[{ropts = SystemOptions["ReduceOptions"]}, 
  Internal`WithLocalSettings[
   SetSystemOptions[
    "ReduceOptions" -> "SolveDiscreteSolutionBound" -> 10^(14)], 
   Solve[y^2 == 2213326116 + 94098 x (1 + x) (-31363 + 31366 x) && 
     10^(13) <= y <= 10^(14) && x >= 2, {y, x}, Integers], 
   SetSystemOptions[ropts]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: No, there isn't a way to parallelize this.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok, and another way to speed it up?

Comment: @Jan speeding up `Solve` is, obviously, non-trivial. However, in answering [your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/212522/27951) from which you got this code, Roman proposed [an alternative to `Solve` using a brute-force approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212529/27951). Have you tried it here?

Comment: @MarcoB yes but it is in no way faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want $10^{13}\leq y\leq 10^{14}$, so obviously $10^{26}\leq y^2\leq 10^{28}$. The range of $x$ for which your expression $10^{26}\leq y^2 = 2213326116 + 94098\ x\ (1 + x) (-31363 + 31366\ x)\leq 10^{28}$ can be easily found:

```
N@Reduce[10^26 < 2213326116 + 94098 x (1 + x) (-31363 + 31366 x) <= 10^28, x]
```

> `323584. < x <= 1.50194*10^6`

That's not a huge range; we can brute-force test all values of $x$ in that range, *and* we can do that in parallel, e.g. using `ParallelDo`:

```
ParallelTable[
 If[
   IntegerQ@Sqrt[2213326116 + 94098 x (1 + x) (-31363 + 31366 x)],
   x, Nothing
 ],
 {x, 300000, 1600000}
]
```

This is not exactly fast, but it does finish within two minutes on my 4-core machine, whereas your `Solve` expression was still chugging away after a couple of minutes. This is an [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) operation, i.e. it suffers from no interdependence or communication overhead, so it should see a nice boost from extensive parallelization on many kernels.

Unfortunately, however, it appears that there are no results in that range that this method could find.

Comment: Note that to `Sow` in parallel is [not straightforward](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84534/reap-sow-with-parallelize-bad-performance-why).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good point. I even knew that at some point :-( Let me change it to `ParallelTable` just to avoid that headache.