# Finding if a number is perfect square

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, number-theory

I used the following code to found if a specific number is a perfect square:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ParallelTable[
  If[IntegerQ[Sqrt[ ...]], ..., Nothing], {..., ..., ...}] //. {} -> 
  Nothing
```

Mathematice can do this for numbers up to:

```
$MaxMachineNumber
```

> ```
> 1.79769*10^308
> ```

But my code is way, way too slow. Is there an other way to write the code in Mathematica that will be much faster?

I would accept a recommendation to use another programming language to find if a number is a perfect square for large values (like $10^{12}$ and bigger)? I know that `ULLONG_MAX` in C++ can handle values up to $18446744073709551615$. But code in C++ is slow for larger values. I also thought about using [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number#Properties) of square numbers in my program, but that means that I also need to compute the values.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/442)?

Comment: @J.M.'sennui Yes I saw, but I am using Mathematica 12.0. What program is the fastest? And are they faster than using a pure C++ pogram that can parallize a lot of calculations?

Comment: @m_goldberg No it does not. See my comment above.

Comment: You may also be interested in the internal function ``NumberTheory`PowersRepresentationsDump`ProbablePerfectSquareQ``.

Comment: @Derik if the missing link is “what approach is the fastest”, then you should benchmark each approach on your computer to see.

Comment: In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/230008/26598) I use a C function `isqrt` that computes integer square roots and that will return `-1` if a number is not a perfect square. It's quite fast and may work for you too. Depending on your use case you can set `myint` to be 64-bits instead of 128-bits (using `typedef int64_t myint;` at the beginning of the code), which will make the code still much faster.

Comment: [Here are some more ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18686659) for a fast C code.