# Check if a fraction leads to an integer, choose $r$ and run trough $0\le a\le n$ and go to $r+1$

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, code-review, number-theory, number-representation

Well, I am trying to do the following: I have two functions $y(r,a)$ and $z(r,a)$ and I want to check of the division of both those functions leads to an integer. In order to do that I want to choose the value of $r$ run through $0\le a\le n$ and go to $r+1$ and test again $0\le a\le n$. And so on. How can I do that?

I also want to use the `Monitor[]` function to visually see what the current status is $r$ and $a$. I know that I can do that using `Monitor[Parallelize[While[True,If[IntegerQ[...],Print[...]];...++];...],...]`. But from that point on I do not know.

---

Example:

$y(r,a)$:

```
-34 + Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
  3 (-4 + r)^2 + 45 a^2 (-2 + r) - 2 a (-11 + r) (-2 + r) + 
   4 a^3 (-8 + r)^2] + 3 r
```

$z(r,a)$

```
9 (-a + r)
```

So it has to check when $\frac{y(r,a)}{z(r,a)}$ is an integer. For $3\le r\le10^3$ and $0\le a\le10^4$

Comment: Could you please add a concrete example like you always do?

Comment: @Syed I did that.

Comment: Please choose a typical `n` and show what values you want `a` and `r` to go through. `Range[0,n]` gets you the values from 0 to n, but what does it mean for `r` to go to `r+1`?

Comment: @Syed I edit it again ;).

Comment: And may I ask why a simple nested loop would not be sufficient for this purpose?

Comment: @Syed I do not know how I make such a loop and how I can monitor the progress.

Comment: [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/230005/26598) may help you with some tricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only addressing the question of how to do this calculation fast, not the progress indicator question.

```
y[r_, a_] = -34+Sqrt[3]Sqrt[3(-4+r)^2+45a^2(-2+r)-2a(-11+r)(-2+r)+4a^3(-8+r)^2]+3r;
z[r_, a_] = 9(-a+r);
```

Notice that a necessary condition for $y(r,a)/z(r,a)$ to be integer is that the number under the square root in $y(r,a)$ is a perfect square. With [this superfast perfect-square detector](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207813/26598)

```
sQa = FractionalPart@Sqrt[# + 0``1] == 0 &;
```

we can find a list of candidate solutions in about one minute:

```
candidates = Reap[Do[If[sQa[3(3(-4+r)^2+45a^2(-2+r)-2a(-11+r)(-2+r)+4a^3(-8+r)^2)],
                        Sow[{r, a}]], {r, 3, 10^3}, {a, 0, 10^4}]][[2, 1]];
```

Among these, there is no solution for the full question:

```
Select[candidates, Divisible[y @@ #, z @@ #] &]
(*    {}    *)
```

Further speedups:

- use `ParallelDo` instead of `Do`; use a [parallelized version of `Sow`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/329/26598) to collect candidates
- compile something?
- use C instead of Mathematica: for example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/230008/26598)