# Using more than 6 kernels in ParallelTable function

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation, parallelization, number-theory, big-numbers

I have the following code:

```
ParallelTable[
 If[IntegerQ@Sqrt[80892036 + 17994 x (1 + x) (-5995 + 5998 x)], x, 
  Nothing], {x, 6694300, 31072325}]
```

It uses 6 kernels to compute the result. Is it possible to speed it further up, by for example using more kernels?

Comment: Yes. But that depends (i) on your hardware and (ii) on your _Mathematica_ license. Notice that _Mathematica_ does not use nor count virtual cores, only physical ones. (Hyperthreading is usually pointless for well-written numerical code.)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher what does it depend on for the hardware, I've an intel core i7 8gen and 32 gb of ddr4 ram. And I've the Professional version of Mathematica

Comment: So how many cores does the processor have? Maybe 6?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher yes 6 cores and 12 threads

Comment: As I said, _Mathematica_ does not care about hyperthreads. So 6 cores is the maximum that can be used by _Mathematica_.

Comment: Just to point out the bottleneck: These computations cannot be performed in machine integers because the numbers are too large. So the integer arithmetic has to be emulated in software. So without further mathematical tricks, this also cannot be compiled (which would be done by `Table`/`ParallelTable` automatically if possible).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher So I can not speed up my calculation, that is the conclusion?

Comment: No. So far, we only know that it cannot be sped up _by brute force_. But there might be cleverer algorithms out there.

Comment: Please, if you use a brute force search to find solutions, use the fast square root options in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/442/fastest-square-number-test/207813#207813) question. For example, results are returned 25 times faster by using sQ from @MichaelE2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can launch as many subkernels as you want (and as your license allows) using [`LaunchKernels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaunchKernels.html). Mathematica launches as many as the number of CPU cores by default, but you can specify the exact number you want, and you can launch more.

Using more subkernels than the number of CPU cores you have will typically lead to no performance improvement at all. Sometimes it leads to worse performance. In rare cases, it may be worth doing with a hyperthreading CPU. I strongly recommend you do some benchmarks to verify that you do actually gain performance before launching more subkernels than the number of CPU cores.