# Speeding up FactorInteger for product of two primes

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, prime-numbers, factorization

I have a large integer $N$ of size about 10^150. I know that $N$ is a product of two primes $p$ and $q$. I also know that both $p$ and $q$ are of roughly equal size, so one of them is not, for example, 2 or 3.

Can I use this information to somehow speed up `FactorInteger` ?
Or is factoring such a large number already beyond the scope of a average desktop computer.
I also noticed that `FactorInteger` uses one of my cpu cores only, is it possible to parallelize this?

Comment: Maybe start around `Sqrt[n]` (avoiding `N` because of its built in definition), which, since the prime counting function is about $\text{li}(x)$, is approximately equal to `Prime[Floor[LogIntegral[Sqrt[n]]]]`? Then work your way down `Prime[k]` manually (as long as you start above `Sqrt[n]`)? No idea if this is remotely a good idea, though, since I don't know how mathematica deals with `Prime`. But you could probably parallelize it easily, at least! :P

Comment: How about implementing the general number field sieve as it's the most efficient:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve

Comment: @Dominic thanks, reading this led me to Fermat's optimization method which seems exactly what I need

Comment: I'm sure you know RSA numbers take a long time to factor even with efficient algorithms and yours seems in this group.  Note the list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers are all composed of equal-sized factors.  Even RSA-100 I think is practically beyond desktop computers.

Comment: @Dominic : Until polynomial selection stops being a black art, this is not a productive suggestion.  See, e.g., [http://www.math.ttu.edu/~cmonico/software/ggnfs/] for GGNFS, and other implementations have similar weaknesses in polynomial selection.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on "p and q are of roughly equal size". If they differ no more than say 10^6, the following works rather fast. E.g.:

```
fac[big_] := Module[{ne = NextPrime[Sqrt[big] - 1]},
  While[Mod[big, ne] > 0, ne = NextPrime[ne]];
  {ne,big/ne}
  ]
n = 80;
fac[NextPrime[10^n] NextPrime[10^n + 10^6] ]

(* {100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000001000507, \
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
00000000129} )*
```

Comment: `! Divisible[big, ne]` is slightly faster than `Mod[big, ne] > 0` because it does not need to actually compute the modulus.

Answer (score 2):

If x is around 10^150, let y = floor(sqrt(x)), and if y^2≠x then solve (y+k+1)(y-k)=x, (y+k+2)(y-k) = x, (y + k + 3)(y - k) = x etc. until you find a k that is an integer. This will cover a huge range, much larger than 10^6.

We know 0 <= d = x - y^2 <= 2y ≈ 2 x 10^75.

Take for example (y+k+2)(y-k) = y^2 + yk + 2y - ky - k^2 - 2k. We solve 2y - k^2 - 2k = d or k^2 + 2k + 1 = 2y +1 - d. k will be between sqrt(y) and sqrt(2y), that is between 4.5 x 10^37 and 6.3 x 10^37. You can halve the number of calculations by not calculating k if the solution would have to consist of an even and an odd number.

(y+k+c)(y-k) = x will have a solution around sqrt (cy) = sqrt(2c) * x^(1/4). j calculations let you cover even c up to 2c, with factors up to 4 sqrt(j) x^(1/4) apart.

Comment: Have you tried to program your idea?

Comment: @gnasher729, I assume this a known algorithm. If it is, what is it called?

Answer (score 2):

Translating some of @gnasher729's suggestions to Mathematica gives indeed a superfast recipe:

```
$MaxExtraPrecision = 10^3;
f[x_Integer] := Module[{y, i, z, s},
  y = Floor[Sqrt[x]];
  Catch[
    i = 0;
    While[True,
      z = (2 y + i)^2 - 4 x;
      If[z >= 0 && IntegerQ[Sqrt[z]],
        s = i/2 + y + {1, -1} Sqrt[z]/2;
        If[IntegerQ[s[[1]]] && IntegerQ[s[[2]]], Throw[s]]];
      i++]]]

f[15]
(*    {5, 3}    *)

f[16]
(*    {4, 4}    *)

f[17]
(*    {17, 1}    *)

n = 80;
f[NextPrime[10^n] NextPrime[10^n + 10^6]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*    {0.010925,
       {100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000507,
        100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000129}}    *)

f[NextPrime[10^n] NextPrime[10^n + 10^12]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*    {0.007086,
       {100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000191,
        100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000129}}    *)
```

Things get a lot slower once the difference between the two numbers becomes larger than their square root:

```
f[NextPrime[10^n] NextPrime[10^n + 10^43]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*    {132.132,
       {100000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000357,
        100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000129}}    *)
```

The remaining point is a fast method to determine `IntegerQ[Sqrt[z]]` for very large values of `z`. Using [@MichaelE2's fast perfect-square test](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/442/fastest-square-number-test) gives a 150-fold speedup, which is however no match for the exponentially increasing difficulty with factor-spacing:

```
$MaxExtraPrecision = 10^3;
f[x_Integer] := Module[{y, i, z, s},
  y = Floor[Sqrt[x]];
  Catch[
    i = 0;
    While[True,
    z = (2 y + i)^2 - 4 x;
    If[z >= 0 && FractionalPart[Sqrt[z + 0``1]] == 0,
      s = i/2 + y + {1, -1} Sqrt[z]/2;
      If[IntegerQ[s[[1]]], Throw[s]]];
    i++]]]

n = 80;
f[NextPrime[10^n] NextPrime[10^n + 10^43]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*    {0.894308,
       {100000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000357,
        100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000129}}    *)

f[NextPrime[10^n] NextPrime[10^n + 10^44]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*    {92.1891,
       {100000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000179,
        100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000129}}
```

Comment: For `IntegerQ[Sqrt[z]]` try `(Count[JacobiSymbol[#, Prime /@ Range[1, Ceiling[1 + Log[2, #]]]], -1] == 0 &)` to get strong probably square-ness.  Test with, e.g., the non-square 853973422267356706546355086954657449503488853576566997801404568608559958358411214284271742350323575809430922219 and the square 853973422267356706546355086954657449503488853576566997800752173762579354251844397804033888338676797897369495524.

Comment: It's easy to prove that a `False` result is correct.  I don't know if there are (named analogously) Euler-Jacobi pseudo-squares.  Also the upper limit, `Ceiling[...]`, could be lowered substantially since most primes are greater than $2$.

Comment: Thanks @EricTowers for the suggestion. Your method as presented is not much faster than the plain `IntegerQ[Sqrt[z]]` and I've decided to go with @MichaelE2's [simple-yet-superfast method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207813/26598) for now.

Comment: It was >30-times faster in `RepeatedTiming[]`s on my hardware, but of course, I'm not using your hardware.