# How can I test if the sum of two divisors of a number add up to a perfect square?

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization, number-theory, number-representation, factorization

Let's say I have a number $n$ and I want to find the divisors of $n$, I can do that using `Divisors[n]`. That will generate a list `{...,...,...}` which are the divisors of $n$. Now the question: how can I test if the sum of two divisors of the number $n$ add up to a perfect square?

For example the number $n=6$ as the following divisors `{1,2,3,6}` and we can notice that $1+3=2^2$ and $3+6=3^2$. So I want Mathematica to spit out two things:

1. I want Mathematica to give `True` is there are two numbers in the divisors that add up to a perfect square;
2. And I want Mathematica to find the two numbers that add up to the perfect square.

Comment: What have you tried? I see zero code in the question...

Comment: @ciao I have no idea how to code that in Mathematica.

Comment: https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/

This is not a "do my work for me" stack. 

Give it a try, *then* if you have problems, post the code in a question.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Fastest square number test](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/442/26598).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First take a outer product to get all the pairs

```
d=Divisors[n];    
prod = Flatten[Outer[List, d, d], 1]
```

Then e.g. define a function like this

```
    IsSquare[{a_, b_}] := Module[{check},
  check = IntegerQ[Sqrt[a + b]];
  If[check == True, Print[{a, b}]];
  check
  ]
```

and apply it to the outer product

```
IsSquare /@ prod
```

which will print all the pairs that satisfy your condition and returns a list with True or False. This now you can adapt to your specific need.

Answer (score 0):

Only slightly different to @Andrzej , thought I'd give it a go

```
n = 2;
d0 = Divisors[n]
d = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Tuples[%, 2]]
Sqrt /@ ((#[[1]] + #[[2]]) & /@ %)
IntegerQ /@ %
d[[#]] & /@ Position[%, True]
```

Little more clunky but maybe `Tuples[]` will help