# improving efficiency of a code

Tags: performance-tuning

I have the code:

```
SquareEdges[n_Integer?Positive] := 
 Reap[Do[If[IntegerQ[Sqrt[Prime[i + 1] + Prime[j + 1]]], 
     Sow[{i, j}]], {i, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}]][[2, 1]]

results = {};
n = 13;
While[n < 10001, poss = SquareEdges[n];
 gr = Graph[poss, VertexLabels -> Automatic];
 numNodes = Length[Select[VertexOutDegree[gr], # < 1 &]];
 AppendTo[results, numNodes];
 n++]
Print[results]
```

It seems to be working quite slowly. How can I improve the speed of it?

Comment: What is `SquareEdges`? It seems to be undefined.

Comment: thx henrik! I have edited it to contain the full code. It did not show it completeley for some reason

Comment: [See here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207813/26598) for a faster way to check if an integer number is a perfect square (much faster than your `If[IntegerQ[Sqrt[...]]]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear[SquareEdges]
SquareEdges[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Reap[Do[If[IntegerQ[Sqrt[Prime[i + 1] + Prime[j + 1]]], 
     Sow[{i, j}, ToString@n]], {i, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}]][[2, 1]]
```

You don't have to calculate these repeatedly as every iteration adds a few more entries. The following lookup takes `5.8s` on my machine.

```
lut = SquareEdges[1001];
```

Now you can lookup from this table and `Sow` instead of `Append`:

```
n = 13;
Reap[While[n < 1001, poss = Select[lut, Last@# <= n &];
    gr = Graph[poss(*,VertexLabels\[Rule]Automatic*)];
    Sow[Length[Select[VertexOutDegree[gr], # < 1 &]]
     ];
    n++]][[2, 1]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

---

*Result*

> {3.16412, {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3,
> 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6,
> 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8,
> 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
> 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,
> 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6,
> 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
> 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
> 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
> 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
> 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
> 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
> 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12,
> 12, 13, 12, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 8,
> 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8,
> 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7,
> 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
> 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
> 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7,
> 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5,
> 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
> 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
> 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,
> 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,
> 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,
> 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9,
> 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8,
> 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
> 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
> 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 5,
> 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
> 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
> 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
> 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
> 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
> 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
> 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
> 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
> 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
> 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
> 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
> 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
> 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
> 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
> 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
> 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}}

Comment: thanks for answering! Another question: Is ther anything I can do to get the estimated time of this code? cuz I am planning to run it for 1000000 numbers.

Comment: My knowledge about Graphs is quite superficial. I would suggest that you  follow the modifications suggested by Henrik Schumacher and post a fresh question when you have given it your best shot.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what Syed already pointed out, you can speed up the search for the restricted set of edges by using a `SparseArray` and by using `Table` instead of `Sow` and `Reap`. Moreover, I suggest to employ `Count` because it is more idiomatic (and also a bit faster because it does not have to create sets first):

```
A = SparseArray[lut -> _, {1001, 1001}];
result = Table[
  Count[VertexOutDegree[Graph[A[[1 ;; n, 1 ;; n]]["NonzeroPositions"]]], 0]
  , {n, 13, 1000}];
```

Originally, I meant to propose

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 A = SparseArray[lut -> _, {1001, 1001}];
 result = Table[
   Differences[A[[1 ;; n, 1 ;; n]]["RowPointers"]]
   , {n, 13, 1000}];
 ]
```

which is 10 times faster (because it avoid `Graph` altogether).
But it gives a different result if not all vertices of from `1` to `n` appear in `loss = A[[1 ;; n, 1 ;; n]]["NonzeroPositions"]`. Not sure whether you want the one or the other...

The idea is that you use `A[[1 ;; n, 1 ;; n]]` (or rather its symmetrization) as the adjacency matrix of an undirected graph. Then `rp = A[[1 ;; n, 1 ;; n]]["RowPointers"]` contains the numbers of nonzeroes per row (== number of edges a vertex is attached to).
More precisely, vertex `i` has `rp[[i+1]] - rp[[i]]` neighbors.