# Enumeration of a certain sequence IV

Tags: code-request, integer-sequence

Let $F_n$ denote the $n$-th Fibonacci number. I am interested in the sequence $$a(k, n)=\left | \left \{0 \leq m \leq n: \frac{F_m}{k} \; \text{is a perfect square}  \right \} \right |,$$
where $|\cdot|$ denotes the cardinality of a set.

For example, $a(1, 100) = 4$ since there are only four perfect squares among the first $n=100$ Fibonnaci numbers: $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, $F_2=1$ and $F_{12}=144$.

How can I write a code to calculate $a(k, n)$?

Comment: What is `perfect square`?

Comment: @cvgmt, I think this is a common synonym for a [square number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number).

Comment: @Domen  I know `Perfect triangle numbers` etc. but I do not know `Perfect square`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not give an example. Is this what you want?

Using Michael E2 code to check for perfect square from [Fastest square number test](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/442/fastest-square-number-test)

```
ClearAll[a,sQ];
sQ[n_]:=FractionalPart@Sqrt[n+0``1]==0;
a[k_Integer,n_Integer?Positive]:=Table[f=Fibonacci[m]/k; If[sQ[f],m,Nothing],{m,0,n}];
a[1,100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Length[%]
(*4*)
```

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding. The horizontal brackets denote cardinality.

Comment: $a(n,k)$ is essentially the number of integers $m$ less than $n$ such that $F_m/k$ is a perfect square.

Comment: @user227351 Ok, if all what you want is the number of integers $m$ that satisfy this, then simply it will be the length of the result. No? Will update.

Comment: I am not that competent, but SquareFreeQ ask "Is $n$ square free?" not "Is $n$ not a square?".

Comment: @user227351 let me check again. Will delete this for now meanwhile until I am sure I understand better the question.

Comment: @user227351 could you check if this is now what you meant? Found a test for perfect square.  So in this example, the length is 3.

Comment: The code is correct. Just the output should be the cardinality.

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much!